# How to fix the dynamic domains issue in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have created a new model named `product.service.type`. Then, in `product.product` model, I have also created a `Many2many` field (named `service_type`, pointing to `product.service.type` model).

Now I have the model `test`, which has `product_id` and `service_type_id` fields, both `Many2one` pointing to `product.product` and `product.service.type` respectively.

What I want is that if you select a product, the service type domain changes to show only the service types of the selected product. I managed this through an `onchange`:

```py
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
    if product_id:
        product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(
            cr, uid, [product_id], context=context)
        service_type_ids = product.service_type.mapped('id')
        return {
            'domain': {
                'service_type_id': [('id', 'in', service_type_ids)],
            },
        }
```

This is working great, the problem is when you are editing the record (not creating a new one), because in this case the `onchange` is not being executed and therefore, the domain shows all service types.

You can see the same problem in partners form, with the field `title`. Create a new partner which is a company, the domain of `title` field changes to allow you select only records like *Corp.*, *Ltd.*, etc., but if you set that the partner is a contact, you can select among records like *Doctor*, *Madam*, *Miss*, etc. Now, save the partner with the data you want, and go to other menu of the topbar. Return to partners form and open the created partner to edit it. Check the `title` field without changing the `is_company` field. Now you have all titles available, despite your partner belongs to a specific class (company or contact).

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, with list of following points. It can be achieve.

- Update context with product_id in that many2many field, xml side.
- Override *search()* method of Product service type model
- Check if you receive same context and fire your logic otherwise return super() method

For example:

```py
@api.model
def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):
    context = self._context or {}

    # Display product list which has not included in CofA Template
    if context.get('product_service_id'):
        product = self.env['product.product'].browse(context.get('product_service_id'))
        service_type_ids = product.service_type.mapped('id')
        args += [('service_type_id', 'not in', service_type_ids)]

    return super(ProductServiceType, self).search(args,
                                               offset,
                                               limit,
                                               order,
                                               count=count)
```

In XML side:

```xml
<field name="product_id"/>
<field name="many2many_field" context="{'product_service_id': product_id}">
```

NOTE: I have tried to answer as per new API and haven't tested it. You need to convert it with old API or as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but unfortunately it is not working. You told me to add XML context to the `many2many` field, but this field exists in `product.product` (named `service_type`) and in `product.service.type` (named `product_ids`). Don't you mean to add that context to the Many2one field named `service_type_id` in `test` model? I also did this, but `search` is not even being executed.

Answer (score 0):

On your model `test`, beside your 2 fields, you need one additional many2many that related to field `service_type` of object `product.product`. Then give domain to your field `service_type_id`.

Here is the illustration,

On model `product.product` you have:

1. `service_type` (m2m to `product.service.type`)

On model `test` you have:

1. `product_id` (m2o to `product.product`)
2. `service_type_id` (m2o to `product.service.type`)
3. `available_service_type_ids` (m2m related/computed to `service_type` of `product.product`)
4. On your xml, `service_type_id` will have domain `[(id , in, available_service_type_ids and available_service_type_ids[0] and available_service_type_ids[0][2] or False)]`